# Slash and python cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to implement a python cmd, using the cmd module. I want to autocomplete files, so I've implemented some methods, however, I've seen that the text parameter from "complete_put(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):" strips all the '/' characters. Anyone knows why, and how can I avoid this behaviour? Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add more detail? Show us your source code! What have you tried? What's your use case? What works? What didn't? Thanks!

Comment: This is what I tried: http://pastebin.com/Zwie5uRW I've put a trace in the complete_put method, to see what text is. if line is "put /", text is "". I've tried this on python 2, btw.

Comment: It sounds like you have a good idea of what you expect the behavior to be, if you could translate this into a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) it will make your question easier to answer.

Comment: Didn't know how post code in the comments, so I created an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. Just had to modify the set_completer_delims attributes.

Comment: Nowadays that doesnt exist anymore (or I just cant find it?) The Solution is adding the slash to the `identchars` attribute.

Comment: @S0lll0s The `set_completer_delims`is found in the **readline** module.
I just did:   `delims = readline.get_completer_delims()`and then `readline.set_completer_delims(delims.replace('/', ''))`. This will configure the readline module appropriately for this scenario.
It works just fine (Python 3.4).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used, it's based on several examples found on the Internet.

```
import os
import cmd
import readline
class Shell(cmd.Cmd, object):
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

    def __complete_path(self, path=None):
        return ['/bin', '/boot', '/etc']

    def do_put(self,args):
        print args

    def complete_put(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        print text
        if not text:
            return self.__complete_path()
        return self.__complete_path(text)
```

Comment: Just try Shell().cmdloop() and use 'put /' <tab>. It should be 'put /bin /boot /etc'