# How to allow argument containing spaces with python3 cmd library?

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I'm using `cmd` library to create simple command line interface with code completion. Problem occurs when command argument contains special characters. Code completion runs only on last part separated by these special characters.

Here is simple code to test it:

```
class Test(Cmd):
    def complete_test(self, text, line, b, e):
    print(text)
    print(line)
    print(b)
    print(e)
```

Type `test` and argument containing, for example, slash. Only last part after `/` is included in `text`, and if you return something, only this last part gets replaced.

I used comments under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11223067/2727064) answer to fix problems with other special characters. But I can't just do `readline.set_completer_delims("")`, because code completion does not work. I need to at least set space as delimiter (`readline.set_completer_delims(" ")`), so that it code completion finds where argument starts. But now I can't pass paths containing spaces (see my completion code below):

```
def complete_export(self, text:str, line:str, begidx, endidx):
    return [x for x in glob(text + "*") if x.startswith(text)]
```

My `export` command only requires one argument - path, so ideal behavior would be to consider first space as beginning of argument and other spaces would be considered part of path.

Note: I have realized that it's possible to use `line` argument, and extract path manually, but code completion would still replace only last part, so path would have to be edited. I submitted this as an answer, but it's not very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution manually separating path from `line`, performing globbing and returning only parts of path after spaces that are already present. One problem is, that if paths contain spaces, if you press tab twice, you get suggestions only for rest of text after space. Depending on use case, this might be problem.

```
def complete_export(self, text:str, line:str, begidx, endidx):
    path = line[line.find(" ")+1:]  # get everything after space
    return [" ".join(x.split(" ")[(line.count(" ") - 1):]) for x in glob(path + "*")]  # completion suggestions after last space
```